# Kernel modules(.ko files) transplant to DLLs export symbols

Tags: linux, dll, module, kernel

In a simulation of project from LINUX module to WINDOWS，we need transplant kernel modules to DLLs.
In the kernel modules, we export symbols by EXPORT_SYMBOL(function) after funciont definition.
In DLL,we could export symbols by __declspec(dllexport) at function definition or def files.
However, if we export symbols by __declspec(dllexport), we must add __declspec(dllexport) before every export function definition. If we export symbols by def files, every module must maintain a def file. 
There are about one million lines codes at this project. The simulation is only a tool of the project, we could not take these two methods for simultion.

Could we export symbols by EXPORT_SYMBOL(function) at DLL，or revise a small amount of code such as EXPORT_SYMBOL macro, or automatic generation def files.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Are you trying to get the same code to compile as both a Windows DLL and a Linux kernel module?

Answer (score 0):

Create a script that will run through the code and for each found EXPORT_SYMBOL(function) will add "function" into .def file.